# How can I delete only the first 2 characters in an output of files?

Tags: bash, shell

when using the find command I get files like this : (find . -type f)

```
./file.txt
./file1.c
./file2.c
```

how can I delete just the './' so I can get an output like this :

```
file.txt
file1.c
file2.c
```

and when I use the tr command : tr -d './' it deletes also the second '.' (./file.txt becomes filetxt)

Comment: `tr -d` doesn't delete a prefix; it deletes *all* characters in the given list: all `.`, all `/`, etc.

Comment: You can do `find . -type f | cut -c 3-`

Comment: I couldn't answer in time, but `find . -type f | sed s/^..//` is also a solution. [Barmar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444767/5825294), however, is probably the shortest possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe to `cut`:

```
find . -type f | cut -c 3-
```